# workaround for bug with GXT ComboBox in Grid

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I created a GXT(Pro) Grid. one of its column contains an enum, which is editable. In order to be able to edit this enum, I created a `ComboBox<Enum>` which is quite simple:

```
public class EnumCombo<E extends Enum<E>> extends ComboBox<E> {

  public EnumCombo(Class<E> clazz) {
    //EnumModelKeyProvider and EnumLabelProvider are my custom classes and are trivial.
    super(new ListStore<E>(new EnumModelKeyProvider<E>()), new EnumLabelProvider<E>());
    for(E e : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
      getStore().add(e);
    }
    setTriggerAction(ComboBoxCell.TriggerAction.ALL); //This line is problematic
  }
}
```

**Bug** : In the grid, when I try to select an element in the ComboBox, The highlighted element is not the one which I hover.

[image: Selection problem]

**Hint** : This does not happen if I remove `setTriggerAction(ComboBoxCell.TriggerAction.ALL);` (but I need to display all values).

**Hint** : This does not happen if the Combo is not in a Grid.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

**EDIT** : The code for **EnumModelKeyProvider** :

```
public class EnumModelKeyProvider<T extends Enum> implements ModelKeyProvider<T> {

  @Override
  public String getKey(T item) {
    return item.name();
  }
}
```

The code for **EnumModelKeyProvider** :

```
public class EnumLabelProvider<T extends Enum<T>> implements LabelProvider<T> {

  @Override
  public String getLabel(T item) {
    return EnumUtils.i18nEnum(item);
  }
}
```

The whole Grid code :

```
public class GridAuditLigne extends Grid<AuditLigne> {

  @Inject
  private GridAuditLigne(GridAuditLignePropertyAccess pa) {
    super(new HasIdListStore<AuditLigne>(), new ColumnModel<AuditLigne>(buildColumnList(pa)));
    getView().setForceFit(true);
    GridEditing<AuditLigne> editing = new GridInlineEditing<AuditLigne>(this);
    ColumnConfig<AuditLigne, AuditLigneStatut> colStatut = getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    editing.addEditor(colStatut, new ComboEnum<AuditLigneStatut>(AuditLigneStatut.class));
    getStore().addSortInfo(new Store.StoreSortInfo<AuditLigne>(pa.controleContratLibelle(), SortDir.ASC));
  }

  public static List<ColumnConfig<AuditLigne, ?>> buildColumnList(GridAuditLignePropertyAccess props) {
    List<ColumnConfig<AuditLigne, ?>> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    result.add(Grids.hidden(new IdCol<AuditLigne>(props.id())));
    result.add(new StringCol<AuditLigne>(props.controleContratLibelle(), "Contrôle"));
    result.add(new StringCol<AuditLigne>(props.controleContratTexte(), "Description"));
    result.add(new EnumCol<AuditLigne, AuditLigneStatut>(props.auditLigneStatut(), "Statut"));
    return result;
  }

  public interface GridAuditLignePropertyAccess extends PropertyAccess<AuditLigne> {

    ValueProvider<AuditLigne, Integer> id();

    @Editor.Path("controleContrat.libelle")
    ValueProvider<AuditLigne, String> controleContratLibelle();

    @Editor.Path("controleContrat.texte")
    ValueProvider<AuditLigne, String> controleContratTexte();

    ValueProvider<AuditLigne, AuditLigneStatut> auditLigneStatut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually the reason for this is a key problem (all elements having the same key, and hence only the first one is selected). But then it shouldn't work outside the Grid, either. You should post your EnumModelKeyProvider and EnumLabelProvider implementations, and also the code where you add your ComboBox to the Grid(Editing).

Comment: @DarekKay Thank you. I think that a problem with keys would prevent the element to be added to the combo. I edited the code to show the 2 providers + the code of the whole grid.

Comment: You are right. Since 3.0.1 (I think) you cannot add elements with the same key anymore. I've tried your example, and it works correctly (after filling the missing classes). However I noticed, that you defined an **EnumCombo** but you're using a **ComboEnum**. Maybe you are using the wrong one? Other than that, I cannot see any problem with your code.